# The optimization of the area of a circle

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization

I need to find the maximum area of a circle that can be achieved with a circumference that equals 25cm. I know that if I am searching for the most optimal shape to make for the maximum area of a figure with a perimeter of 25 is one with infinite sides aka a circle; I am just having trouble proving this idea any suggestions?

Comment: circumference determines radius, radius determines area

Comment: You can use Variational Calculus to prove this.

Comment: If you want a **circle** with circumference $25$ cm, then you have no choice but to have radius $\dfrac{25}{2 \pi}$ and hence the only area you can have is $\dfrac{625}{4 \pi}$.

Comment: I think the question here is not optimizing the circle radius, but proving that given a circumference, a circle is the shape which maximizes area, correct?